# how to import classes not already present in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse IDE- Android Developer tools Build: v22.6.2- 108550

I have to run the program

```
import org.eclipse.gef4.dot.DotExport;    
import org.eclipse.gef4.dot.DotImport;    
import org.eclipse.gef4.graph.Graph;    
import org.eclipse.gef4.zest.core.widgets.GraphWidget;    
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;    
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;    
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;    
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class SampleUsage {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

   Shell shell = new Shell();

   Graph graph = new DotImport(

        "digraph{ "    
        + "node[label=zested]; edge[style=dashed]; "    
        + "1->2; 2->3; 2->4; 3->5; 4->6 "    
        +"}").newGraphInstance();

   open(graph, shell);

   System.out.println(new DotExport(graph).toDotString());

 }

 private static void open(Graph graph, final Shell shell) {

   new GraphWidget(graph, shell, SWT.NONE);

   shell.setText(Graph.class.getSimpleName());    
   shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());    
   shell.setSize(600, 300);    
   shell.open();

   Display display = shell.getDisplay();

   while (!shell.isDisposed())

     if (!display.readAndDispatch())

       display.sleep();

   display.dispose();

 }

}
```

but all the import commands above public class SampleUsage has error or we can say red bulbs with them means these packages are not already present the error is `The import org.eclipse cannot be resolved`. How can I import these packages to my IDE to run this program? If you could tell me the location of these packages as well, that would be great.

Comment: You will have to tell eclipse from where you have to add these classes. You will have to add the JAR/ Library which contains these classes to your project's build path.

Comment: You can add a jar in eclipse by right clicking on the Project --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path. Under Libraries tab, click Add Jars or Add External JARs and give the Jar.

Comment: @AnshuKunal You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a jar in eclipse by right clicking on the **Project --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path.** Under Libraries tab, click Add Jars or Add External JARs and give the Jar.

Answer (score 0):

Well, It seems like you have to go through option 2, but some times option 1 will help you if you have to import existing project.

**Option 1:**

1. **Import the existing project on your eclipse**:  click **File>Import** and select the project which you want to import. If eclipse shows error then click on it and select import the project option manually . If it show problem again then clean all project by click **project> clean**.

**Option 2:**

1. **Adding jar in eclipse**. Step: click **Project> BuildPath > configure build path**. Then click AddJars and select the location of where your jar exists.

Thanks.